# Redirect with www in front of it not working?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following rule which redirects the page "example2.test.com" to "www.example2.test.com/index.shtml"   --- i.e. it appends index.shtml to it

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.test.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example2.test.com/index.shtml [R,L]

If I change the rule to try and catch if a user enters in **www**.example2.test.com as per below I get an error telling me there are too many redirects

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.test.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example2.test.com/index.shtml [R,L]

Is there something I am mising here ??  - im a  bit new to this ..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is basically an if statement, and by default the server will try to access the index page, so what your second example says is

```
if uri is   www.example2.test.com
redirect to www.example2.test.com
```

You're creating an infinite loop, because once it gets redirected it gets reevaluated, which redirects it.

If you're not getting that `index.shtml` page when you visit that url you might need to add `index.shtml` to your apache [directory index](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). so open your `httpd.conf` and find where it says something like

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

and add `index.shtml` to it if it isn't already there so you end up with

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ..I thought I was checking to see if the url is www.example2.test.com - IF YES - then redirect and add index.shtml to it .... if its not doing that how do I stop the infinite loop ?